# Toggle and disable/enable one checkbox when another checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, asp-classic, checkbox

I've enjoyed this site for the past year or so and looking forward to some help from all of you.

I'm working on a classic asp page (I inherited the page, didn't create it) that has a table that is populated by a recordset.  Each record from the recordset generates a new row on the table, based on whatever criteria that is selected. For sake of explanation and simplicity, if one selects 1 store or 1000 stores, the table will generate that many rows. Assuming there were two records selected, the table will look like below:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Store 1</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkFoo<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>"/>Foo</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkBar<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>" class="Bar"/>Bar</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkDo<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>"/>Do</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkRe<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>" class="Re"/>Re</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkMe<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>"/>Me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Store 2</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkFoo<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>"/>Foo</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkBar<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>" class="Bar"/>Bar</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkDo<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>"/>Do</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkRe<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>" class="Re"/>Re</td>
    <td><input type=checkbox value="" name="chkMe<%=rsR2.AbsolutePosition%>"/>Me</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Each object gets its own name based on the record position.  I'm practically new to javascript and jquery (trying to learn it in the last year or so), but what I want to do is this:  if someone clicks on the checkbox titled **"Re"**, I want to disable and check the checkbox titled **"Bar"** *on that same row.*  Essentially, if **Re** is checked, **Bar** has to be checked prior to submission of the form.

I tried the following jquery code, but I'm struggling with it.

```
$('.Re').live('click', function () {
    var n = $(this).siblings('Bar');
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    n.prop('disabled', true); 
    } else {
        n.prop('disabled', false);
    } 
});
```

I also tried to follow this link (among others) to no avail.  http://bit.ly/15NPhdN.   Any suggestions?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing something like this should do it :

```
$(function() {
    $('table').on('change', '.Re', function () {
        console.log(this.checked)
        $(this).closest('td').siblings('td').find('.Bar').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4RkYn/2/)

note :

- your checkboxes are'nt siblings, as they are nested in TD's
- that the change event is more appropriate for checkboxes
- that a delegated version of `on()` would be better, as `live()` is deprecated
- the `checked` property is what sets/unsets the checked state, not `disabled` ?

Comment: This makes sense; however I tried it to no avail.   Maybe I'm missing something?

http://jsbin.com/ikuyoc/4/edit

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed your Fiddle code.  I'll inject it in my code and keep you posted.   I think this should do it.

Comment: Try replacing `table` with `document`, as I just used `table`, but if that is dynamic as well, you need an element higher up in the DOM that isn't dynamic.

Comment: Adeneo, I just tried it on the development servers.   Everything seems to work fine, regardless the amount of records.   Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, thanks for the mini-lesson too, as it helped put things into perspective.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('.Re').on('change', function () {
    var n = $(this).siblings('Bar');
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    n.prop('disabled', true); 
    } else {
        n.prop('disabled', false);
    } 
});
});
```